# Vitamio doesn't play m3u8

Tags: android, vitamio

I try to play m3u8 by  Vitamio lib, but it doesn't work.

```
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);
    path = "http://hlsstr01.svc.iptv.rt.ru/hls/CH_24DOC/variant.m3u8?version=2";
    mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Streaming link returns 403 Forbidden.